# Occasional bug with Interesting tags?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-watching

This is something that I've seen a few times this week, but it seems to go away by itself after a while. Clicking on an Interesting tag takes me to the Featured list for that tag sometimes, when usually it just filters all questions by that tag.

I can currently recreate it thus :

1) While on http://stackoverflow.com , I click on one of my Interesting tags (eg sql-server). At this point I am not on the Featured list, nor have I been for at least an hour.
2) The link says https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server
3) It takes me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server as expected, but takes me to the Featured page for it rather than the Active one.
4) This persists until while in one of those tags I click one of the other buttons at the top.

Additional oddities :

1) While on main page, I select Week
2) I click on a tag, expecting to filter the Week section based on it.
3) Instead, I'm presented with the Featured list for that tag again.

I can also click on Hot on the main page, select a tag and get the featured list again.

I've been trying to work out a pattern to the odd behaviour, but nothing yet. At first I thought it was an issue with the selected tag not having an equivalent to the screen you were previously on (Active/Week), and therefore selecting Featured by default. But it's not that.

Has anyone else experienced this, or can recreate it every time? Or am I missing something obvious?

FWIW, I'm using Opera 10.01 and I've seen this on 3 different PCs and XP32/XP x64/Win7 Pro 64-bit.

EDIT : Ok, after nosing around the Questions page for a change rather than just the main page, the behaviour when clicking on the Interesting Tags is consistent - it will remain on the tab you selected within the Questions page. However, when starting from the main address http://stackoverflow.com the behaviour is somewhat confusing. If I'm on the address https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured and I click on an Interesting Tag, I expect it to take me to the Featured tab for that tag. Instead, it takes me to the Questions for that tag, and the tab shown is whatever I last used on the Questions page (which in my latest test case was Newest). So, I now understand what it's doing...but it's sometimes acting counter-intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO remembers on which tab of the question page you were before. After clicking an interesting tag you are directed to this remembered tab of the question page.

You can test it:

1. Navigate to the *Questions* page
2. Click tab *votes*
3. Navigate to the main page
4. Click an *Interesting Link*
5. -> *votes* tab

---

1. Navigate to the *Questions* page
2. Click tab *featured*
3. Navigate to the main page
4. Click an *Interesting Link*
5. -> *featured* tab

Comment: That is the way I expect it to work. It is not the way I always see it working.

Comment: Actually realised I never actually click on the Questions page - everything takes up twice the space and I don't see any real benefit to it.

Comment: The question page is ordered by the date when the question was asked, not when the last one touched it. So you can see the latest questions. That's its purpose. And you can read the first lines of the question without needing a tooltip.